# issues with eclipse plugin decorator

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins, decorator, readonly

I'm adjusting my current eclipse plugin for some gimmicks and made my own decorator for files and folders. the current file decorator looks like this:

```
<decorator
  lightweight="true"
  id="com.tdm.eclipse.plugin.decorators.readonly"
  label="readOnly file decorator"
  icon="icons/readonly.ico"
  state="true"
  location="TOP_LEFT"
  adaptable="true">
  <description>
    readOnly file decorator
  </description>
  <enablement>
     <and>
     <objectClass name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
     <objectState name ="readOnly" value="true"/> 
     </and>
  </enablement>
</decorator>
```

current issues:

I.) if the file permission is changed to writeable the file decorator doesn't change unless you reload the project again (file out of sync error sometimes).

II.) I want to use the decorator for specific files only (currently ALL read only files get decorated). tried to use nameFilter but it isn't allowed inside the decorator or objectState/objectName.

Any clues how to fix my issues? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a decorator class (specify the `class` attribute) rather than using the `icon` attribute.

The `ILightweightLabelDecorator`

```java
public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration)
```

method will be passed the `IFile` as the element so you can do your filtering on that.

To deal with the file read only attribute changes you will have to use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for resource changes.

When you detect a attribute change you can tell the decorator manager to update:

```java
IDecoratorManager decoratorMgr = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();

decoratorMgr.update("your decorator id");
```

You can use

```xml
<objectState name ="extension" value="file extension"/>
```

to filter by file extension in the extension point.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. already tampered with decorator classes but thought doing it within the plugin.xml would be a lot shorter. is the icon for specific files at least doable with xml only?

Comment: already too late to edit so I'll have to post again: another potential problem could be that the file permission change isn't done within eclipse but from an external script. would the IResourceChangeListener even notice it??

Comment: Eclipse doesn't see external changes at all until the workspace is refreshed or you specify the 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' preference.

Comment: You can filter by file extension - see updated answer

Comment: thanks exactly the information I was looking for but seems 'refresh using native hooks or polling' doesn't update the decoration. perhabs it only works with an IResourceChangeListenener as you suggested